# Why isn't Parsley validating the form?

Tags: javascript, meteor, parsley.js

I'm currently playing with parsley and trying to put it into my Meteor app and I can't seem to use it to validate. I know it's probably just a basic problem but I've been looking for ages and I can't seem to find why it's not.

This is my code.

HTML

```
<head>
<title>interestCalc</title>
```

```
{{> interestCalc}}
```

```
<form id="formInterest" class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="txtInterest" name="txtInterest" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Interest rate</label>

        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <input type="text" data-parsley-required="true" class="form-control" id="txtInterest"
                   placeholder="Interest Rate">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button
                class="btn btn-success"
                id="saveButton"
                type="submit">
            Next
        </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

JS

```
if(Meteor.isClient) {

    Template.interestCalc.events = {

        'click #saveButton': function(e,t) {
            var $form = $('#formInterest');
            if ($form.parsley('validate')) {
                alert('done');
            }
            return false;
        }

    }
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    // code to run on server at startup
  });
}
```

Now as it's just a small learning app so I've just pasted everything on here but I can say that I can get to the click event. However, I would assume that if I had nothing in the textbox, my $form.parsley('validate') call should return false and I shouldn't get the alert button. However, I seem to always be getting the alert box.

Is there something I'm missing about how Meteor or ParsleyJS work?

Answer (score 0):

You have to call the `parsley('isValid')` after calling `validate`.

Sample code:

```
//Validate the inputs
$form.parsley('validate');
// Get the status of validity
var isValid = $form.parsley('isValid');

if (isValid) {
   alert('done');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Template.interestCalc.events` is a function you should call an pass an object to as argument, instead of assigning the object directly to it.